# Tensorflow - Incorrect model inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, dataset, object-detection

I am training a tensorflow model: faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 with a dataset of flowers, more specifically, sunflowers. The images in the dataset are all varied and there is about 500 images which the model is been trained on.

The RCNN model gets to near 1 for total-loss when trained. When running the trained model with the new frozen-graph it can detect a sunflower with a high recognition of around 85%-95%. When passing the model for instance a picture of a person with no sunflowers in that image, the model thinks that the person is a sunflower.

My question, why is the model detecting the image of a person as a sunflower? The model has been trained to detect people previously, is this an issue, or is there an error when training.

Happy to upload model configuration files if required.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe it just missclassifies this image. Have you tried to feed in different images of humans and see if they are wrongly classified?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. Mainly due to it taking so long to classify images. Google themselves said we may need an 'other' field but I aren't sure how that works

Comment: Is the person image included in the training data set ?... May be some 30 to 50 images of person can be included in the training data set